# From average degree to a highly connected subhypergraph

Tags: hypergraph, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

I'm looking for a result in $k$-uniform hypergraphs analogous to the following result for graphs, due to [Mader](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Existenzn-fach-zusammenh%C3%A4ngender-Teilgraphen-in-Mader/b794def6002171cad28960fa63150fec65ba57b4):

Every graph of average degree $4r$ has a $r$-connected subgraph.